# jQuery.forms.js works using click() but not submit() (using selenium)

Tags: jquery, html, forms, selenium

My form has an ajax handler provided by jquery.forms.js.

```
form.ajaxForm({
  dataType: 'json',
  clearForm: true,
  success: function (data)
  {
     form.replaceWith(data);
  }
});
```

I'm testing this using selenium (the python RC interface), and it works when I click() the button, but not when I submit the form:

```
    locbase = "dom=document.forms[0]"
    SEL.type(locbase + ".elements[0]", text)
    SEL.select(locbase+".elements[2]", "label=%s" % username)
    SEL.submit(locbase) # DOESNT WORK
    SEL.click(locbase+".elements[3]") # WORK!
```

By "doesn't work", I mean that the form submits, but not via AJAX.

I guess this is a problem with the form. How can I tell (manually) that both my ajax is bound for both submitting the form and clicking on the button, and what do I have to do to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [FireQuery plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/12632) for firefox to see what jQuery is bound to an element. I tend to use click() when there is a button on the page for form submits. Its very rare that you will see a form that doesnt have a button and if it doesnt you can always do typeKeys() call.

Edit from Comment:

Other than clicking or keyPress I don't think there is a situation where they would submit because normally the submit is bound to a button e.g  or jQuery bindings to a button or there is a listener for keyboard interaction. A user can't submit() something without there being a bound point on the page

Comment: So does this mean its not a problem that submit() doesn't work? What about pressing Enter or something?

Comment: If the Submit button is bound to your jQuery Form then clicking it will be fine, or you can do a keyPress("\13"). I don't know if submit doesn't work but in the 2+ years of using Selenium I have never needed to use submit() on a form

Comment: I mean, is it possible that the user might "submit" the form instead of "click"ing it?

Comment: Other than clicking or keyPress I don't think there is a situation where they would submit because normally the submit is bound to a button e.g `<input type=submit value=submit />` or jQuery bindings to a button or there is a listener for keyboard interaction. A user can't submit() something without there being a bound point on the page.

Comment: Great, thanks. If you could amend your answer to say that you can't have a submit() without a click() without doing something special, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "it doesn't work" do you mean the form does not submit or it submits but not via ajax?

What about a simple test

```
form=ajaxForm{(
 //options
});

form.submit();//does this work?
```

Comment: I mean that it submits, but not via ajax.